# Importing multiple .txt files into r

Tags: r, tibble, txt

I need to import multiple .txt files into R. Each file has multiple sentences in it (for eg, "On Monday, I went to the park.") I would like to be able to import all the files in at the same time and then add them to a tibble, so that I can do text analysis on it.

So far, I have tried

```
#to create vector of txt files
files <- list.files(pattern = "txt$")

# Read all the files and create a FileName column to store filenames
files_list <- files %>%
  set_names(.) %>%
  map_df(read_table2, .id = "FileName")
```

```
my_data <- read.delim(file(files))
```

But I don't know how to actually load the text in each .txt file into the data. When I run this code above, it only reads in the text from one of the files, not all.

I also tried:

```
sapply(files, read.delim)
mainlist = list()
for (i in 1: length(fileList)) {
  mainlist[[i]] = read.delim(files[i], header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
}
```

And while it prints out all the info in each .txt file, when I try to put it in a tibble using

```
mainlist_tib <- tibble(mainlist)
```

the tibble is empty.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Regarding the tibble, I would like for it to have a column for the txt file name and then another column for the text from the file, and then to be able to use the `unnest_tokens()` function to have a tibble where each row contains only one word. Sort of like in the example from the text mining textbook by Silge and Robinson: https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html

Comment: Could you maybe add infomation (i.e. an example) on how you would you tibble to look like?

Comment: One more comment: you should check that you have the correct paths specified: use `list.files( path="data/txt$", full.names=TRUE )`. So your `files` object should contain the full path of each text file in a list.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

files %>%
  set_names(.) %>%
  map_dfr(~readr::read_table(., col_names = F), .id = "FileName")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this definitely helped a lot, but I'm not sure if it created a tibble for the text in the files. If I use 'tibble(files)', then it only returns a tibble with the files names and not the content in the files. And under the 'Environment' pannel in RStudio, there is no new dataframe with the text. I'd like to be able to save the text into a tibble (or dataframe) so that I can call it and do text analyses on it.

Comment: Can you post an example of how your input file looks like?